# Python inheritance problems, return the different value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I have class like this:

```
id_A = 'A'
id_B = 'B'
id_C = 'C'

class A:
    def get_id(self):
        # The expected output: id_A
        return id_A

class B(A):
...
...
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class C(A):
...
...
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

How to use inheritance to enable B and C to output id_ B，id_C?

like:

```
a = A()
b = B()
c = C()

a.get_id (Output should be 'A')
b.get_id (Output should be 'B')
c.get_id (Output should be 'C')
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you at least fill the class ```A``` properly, so we know what your desired basic structure is, e.g. do you want to get the same attribute that is just initialized differently by the subclasses, do you want different attributes that are unique to each class and returned by the same method of the parent class, or just override ```get_id``` in subclasses?

Comment: Yes, I want different attributes that are unique to each class and returned by the same method of the parent class.

Comment: I suppose you could create a property in A, which points to the value to return. B and C can then override this property, so the inherited method in A returns it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as guys suggested, you could **override parent attribute in sub class** like next:

**test.py:**

```
id_A = 'A'
id_B = 'B'
id_C = 'C'

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.identity = id_A

    def get_id(self):
        return self.identity

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.identity = id_B

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.identity = id_C

a = A()
b = B()
c = C()

print(a.get_id())
print(b.get_id())
print(c.get_id())
```

**execution:**

```
# python3 test.py
A
B
C
```

**Update according new coments**, you could also use `classmethod` without `__init__(self)`:

```
id_A = 'A'
id_B = 'B'
id_C = 'C'

class A:
    identity = id_A

    @classmethod
    def get_id(cls):
        return cls.identity

class B(A):
    identity = id_B

class C(A):
    identity = id_C

a = A()
b = B()
c = C()

print(a.get_id())
print(b.get_id())
print(c.get_id())
```

**Execution:**

```
$ python3 test.py
A
B
C
```

Comment: It's close, but is there a way to do it without initializing class?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `without initializing class`? not use `__init__(self)` or not use `a = A()`?

Comment: not use __init__(self)

Comment: See updated answer, you could use `classmethod`